# Android says Damaged SD card at EVERY card

Tags: sd-card, samsung

I faced a problem with my `32 GB SD Card` on `Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime`. Device says `Damaged SD card`. I changed it to a brand new (also 32 GB) SD card... And problem didn't gone. Each card read perfect via card reader, but not on my phone.. What can I do?

Comment: Cell phone and Android questions are off topic here, so this is being voted to be migrated to the proper site to get you the help you seek.

Comment: Run `chkdsk [SDCard Drive Letter] /r` where [ ] is where you will put the drive letter. so the example will look like this `chkdsk D: /r` Example drive letter being D run that then try your card.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin On Windows?

Comment: Yes that is for Windows. On command prompt forgot to say that

Comment: If two cards have become damaged it would suggest that the card reader in the phone is broken.

Comment: Try reading the card with a USB card reader, connected to phone. If fine it confirms what [Burgi](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/162804/burgi) said

Comment: Can you manually format the card in the phone?

Answer (score 0):

The grand prime is known to cause electrical damage to sd cards and without warning. I have two of these phones and they each destroy an sd card every 3 months. The cards may have self sensed damage and dropped into read only mode, in which case you can read them with a usb reader on a desktop but the phone will refuse to mount at all, and the will not be writable in any case.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like it's the card reader in the phone if the cards are working perfectly with other card readers. Also alot of people with the grand prime have been having the same problems at you.